# Data Types manipulation Java

Tags: java

Are character immutable in java. If so, is there a way to change, update or read  multiple char values in a single char variable.

```
String go = "djlfa";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(go);

for(int i = 0; i < go.length(); i++){
    
    Character sym = new Character(sc.next().charAt(i));
    System.out.print(sym);
}
```

Comment: Read multiple char values? A char is one single char. You could make a char array if you needed to store multiple chars. A string is also technically a char array, so that's an even easier way to declare one!

Comment: A `char` has two bytes of memory with UTF-16 encoding and only one byte with UTF-8 encoding.  If you want to store multiple `char`s, then use a `String`; that's what they're made for!

Comment: Note that the `new Character` stuff is unnecessary. `char sym = sc.next().charAt(i);` does largely the same, just without the unnecessary object creation.

Comment: An object being immutable doesn't mean a reference can't be changed.

Comment: I tried using char sym = sc.next().charAt(i); , but it always was giving an exception. And when I analyzed, I don't know if I am really right or wrong. I found that sc.next().charAt(i) scans the entire string then returns the specific position. So, when we use inside a for loop after the first loop. The entire String would have been scanned and will give exception in the second loop, but i find a way by using the string itself without a scanning and using a method in the string class as follows:

Comment: String go = "djlfa";
     
       char c = 'A';
       char o = 97;
 
 for(int i = 0; i < go.length(); i++){
  int k = go.codePointAt(i);
  c = (char)(0 + k);
  System.out.println(c);

   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are character immutable in java

Yes, there is no method to change the value of an existing [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) instance without calling the constructor again.

> If so, is there a way to change, update or read multiple char values
>   in a single char variable

No, this is what [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)s are for. [They are also immutable](https://www.javatpoint.com/immutable-string).

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to put the string `go` into the wrapper type `Character` ?
 If so: `Character` can only store a single character - not 5 (`djlfa`) as you want to do it.

Comment: No I'm trying to do that. I want to update the character as I was working in infix to postfix expressions. And I wanted to test every character read in the expression.